# Обновление другой таблицы контроллером

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть контроллер, который создает запись в таблице message, как правильно реализовать сохранение например отдельного поля телефона в другую таблицу. 
Модель message, в которую записал я метод update_tel не работает, ошибка "неопределенный метод".

```
has_many :info_d

  def self.update_tel params
    InfoD.find_by_user_id(@message.created_user_id)
    InfoD.update_attributes(contact_tel: params[:phone])
  end
```

в модели info_d

```
belongs_to :message
```

Контроллер

```
@message=Message.mesnew(params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save

        MadMailer.new_notify(@message).deliver
        @message.update_tel(params)
        format.html {redirect_to(message_index_path, notice: 'Сообщение добавлено')}
      else
        format.html {render 'new'}
      end
end
end
```

во вьюхе

```
 = f.text_field :phone, value: current_user.info_desk.contact_tel, class: 'form-control'
```

Comment: `InfoD.update_attributes(contact_tel: params[:phone])` што?

Comment: d-side, я же сказал, что не правильно записан мной метод. Что касается обновления данных при создании записи, не понимаю как это происходит, сталкивался только с тем, что при создании записи в одной таблице, создавалась совсем другая запись в другой таблице.

Comment: Нет, секундочку. Вы ж чем-то руководствовались, когда писали эту строчку. Что она вообще должна была означать?

Comment: d-side, руководствовался тем, что написано было 4 года назад кем-то и очень давно. Так как работаю с ror очень мало, а косяки исправлять надо, стараюсь все исправлять, но так как занимаюсь не всегда, делаю глупые ошибки.

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос.

Comment: d-side, InfoD.update_attributes(contact_tel: params[:phone])
В таблице ИнфоД обновить контакт_тел из параметра телефон.

Comment: В таблице. Так. А в какой из её записей?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61143/discussion-between---and-d-side).

Comment: d-side, ответил в чате. Так я же ищу запись по indfo_d.user_id=message.created_user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо D-side за пинки и намеки, терпение, которые помогли разобраться и понять правильную структуру работы с классами и методами.

```
def update_tel params
        info_d=InfoD.find_by_user_id(created_user_id)
        info_d.update_attributes(contact_tel: params.require(:n_message)[:phone])
      end
```